# remote IBM MQ monitoring from power-shell commands / scripts

Tags: powershell, ibm-mq

I am trying to get queue depth for remote IBM MQ using PowerShell script/commands. Seems it is not working correctly, please help.

```
{
$myremoteconns = New-WMQQmgrConnDef -Name T.test.TEST.QM1 -Hostname abcd_testhost01 -Port 1111 -Channel T.test.MQMQ.TESTCHN

$qm = Get-WMQQueueManager -Connections $myremoteconns | where {$_.Name -like 'T.test.TEST.QM1'}
```

> Error New-WMQQmgrConnDef the term 'New-WMQQmgrConnDef' is not recognized

Already installed WebSphere MQ - Windows PowerShell Library from below.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24017698

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that PowerShell cannot find this cmdlet. You need to check if the module you installed is properly found by PowerShell. Check this first:

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable
```

The result will be like:

```
PS C:\Users\username\PowerShell> get-module -ListAvailable


    Directory: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     3.0.1      ImportExcel                         {Import-Html, ConvertFrom-ExcelSheet, PieChart, Import-UPS...}
```

If you don't find the module on the list you can import it manually using:

```
Import-Module -Name 'C:\path\to\module.psm1'
```

In PowerShell (starting at V3) modules should be imported automatically if they are inside on of the path specified in environment variable `PSModulePath`. You can check its value by using:

```
$env:PSModulePath
```

Once you know which folders are included in this variable you can either move the module there or just add another path using

```
$env:PSModulePath = $env:PSModulePath + ";c:\path\to\module"
```

This will work for current session. If you want to modify it for all session you can add the line below to PowerShell profile.

### More info:

- [Importing a module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878284(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Modifying `PSModulePath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878326(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [PowerShell profiles](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles/)

Comment: Hi Robdy , I imported all required modules and now got new error .
 {+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-WMQQueueManager], ParameterBindingValidationException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,WebSphereMQ.GetWMQQueueManager}

Comment: That means you're providing incorrect data to the cmdlet. Check the documentation and `Get-Help` and [this website](https://hursleyonwmq.wordpress.com/2007/12/10/getting-your-websphere-mq-objects-in-the-powershell-next-gen-command-line/). Your question is now related to specific module, which I'm not using so it'd be difficult to resolve it for me.

Comment: Thanks Robdy , I already checked same website and trying to figure out my mistake . Anyone else with MQ information , please help

Comment: I want to monitor queue depth for remote queue using powershell .

Comment: I'd suggest you to ask a new question (you may want to have a look at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as comments are not really good place to look for answers. By the way, if you feel that my answer resolved your issue (with `Error New-WMQQmgrConnDef the term 'New-WMQQmgrConnDef' is not recognized`) feel free to mark it as [accepted answer. More info here.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Thanks , Added new one .